# How to dynamically generate friendly URLS in .htaccess using query string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have reviewed similar questions on SO and cannot find one that fits my needs so this is not a duplicate.

I have a simple `php` page called `top.php`. I pass a parameter in the url like so: `top.php?n=100`.

In my `.htaccess` file I use `mod_rewrite` to change the url to `top-100`. Simple. But what I want to do is not have to hard code every possible url for any number passed as a parameter. Let me elaborate:

`top.php?n=5` | rewrite to `top-5`

`top.php?n=3` | rewrite to `top-3`

`top.php?n=10` | rewrite to `top-10`

And so on.

So how do I create a rewrite using the query string parameter to dynamically generate the friendly url?

Comment: try a regular expression, something like  `top.php\?n=([0-9]+) | top-$1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /top\.php\?n=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /top-%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^top-(\d+)/?$ top.php?n=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```